# Grouping files in tarballs

Tags: bash, scripting

I need your help so as to create some tarballs, so as to group some files by year. I am using the following script but I get the error message:

```
tar: 2067_*.inp: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Code:

```
for i in `seq 1960 2100` ; do
  tar cvf ${i}_74_1.tar ${i}_*.inp
done
```

Where the `*.inp` files have the following structure: `1960_smt.inp`, `1960_smt1.inp`, etc.

I understand that my error is the `*` symbol that can't "understand" that I want to take any character. Could someone please help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> 2067_*.inp: Cannot stat: No such file
>   or directory tar

Sounds more like you don't actually have any files named `2067_XXXX.inp` for `tar` to archive

You'll likely want to check for a matching file to the pattern before you attempt to tar it up:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -u nullglob
for i in {1960..2100}; do
  [ -f ${i}_*.inp ] && tar cvf ${i}_74_1.tar ${i}_*.inp
done
```

#### P.S.

Does anybody know why replacing `[` with `[[ ]]` as in `[[ -f ${i}_*.inp ]]` breaks the pattern matching?

Comment: oops, i am very stupid, the problem was my end wasn't .inp, thanks for pointing this and i had to check again the files

Comment: @kostas updated my answer to provide you with a more robust script

Comment: `[ -f * ]` only works if it represents a single file. Otherwise, you get a "too many arguments" error so its utility is very limited. The reason for the difference is that `[` is a command while `[[` is a syntactic element and the order of evaluation is different for them. Try `set -x; [ -f ${i}_*.inp ]; set +x` and compare it to the same thing with '[[` instead.

Comment: By the way, you can do `shopt -s nullglob` and `files=$(echo *)` or `files=(*)` and `[ -n "$files" ]` or `[[ -n "$files" ]]`.